# In Excel how do subtract values from list table when I preform a transaction?

Tags: excel

If I have two tables where I have list of things in 1 table and the other table serves as a transaction table. But every time I do a transaction the value of units in the transaction should be subtracted from the lists table. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please provide us with more detail. What you mean by “doing a transaction” is not clear. Have you written any macros (in this case you should post them)? Do you simply fill in rows manually and would like the values in the other table to update? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have not used macros. I have two basic sheets, the first table has the list of books and the number of books. The second sheet is the transaction table where I have a drop down of the books from sheet. Now I can issue a number of books in sheet 2 but this number should now be deducted from the original list of books in sheet 1. How can I archive this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say table 1 looks like this:

```
   A             B              C
1 Item      Start Value    Current Value
2 ----      -----------    -------------
3    1           20
4    2          100
5    3           95
```

and table 2 has transactions recorded as a list of Item numbers in column E and associated value movements in column F, then the formula in C3 should be:

```
=B3-SUMIF(E:E,A3,F:F)
```

This formula can then be copied down for the other entries in table 1